# Finding an eqauivalent point in a quadrilateral

Tags: javascript, math, geometry, 2d, coordinates

I am trying to find the rough equivalent point from one quadrilateral to another.

[quadrilateral equivalent point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eExot.png)

What is a good method to find this point?

Any info in the right direction would be great.

Thanks

Comment: This is not possible unless, (at a minimum), the points in one quadrilateral are associated with the corresponding points  in the other one. Simple example, what if one Quadrilateral is a square, and the other is a diamond, and the point in the square you are looking for is near the upper left corner of the square. Do you want the answer to be near the left corner of the diamond, or the top corner ?

Comment: @CharlesBretana Well maybe another way to think about it is, the second quadrilateral is a transformed (scaled, moved, skewed, rotated etc.) version of the first one quadrilateral. Would that make the problem more solvable?

Comment: Yes, if, for all points in the original quadrilateral, (or at least three anyway), it is specified as to which point in the transformed quadrilateral the original point was transformed into.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37544908/  and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37093249/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the points be `[P1, P2, P3, P4]` and assume they are transformed into `[Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4]` by means of an affine transformation of the form `x -> Mx + b` where `M` is a `2x2` matrix and `b` is a constant vector. The idea is to find `M` and apply the transformation to `P` to get `Q`.

Let `v1 = P2 - P1`, `v2 = P3 - P1`, `w1 = Q2 - Q1`, `w2 = Q3 - Q1`. Then `M` is the linear transformation that applies `[v1, v2]` onto `[w1, w2]`. One way to find `M` is by calculating the matrix product

```
M = S * T
```

where `S` is the `2x2` matrix whose columns are the vectors `w1` and `w2` and `T` is the *inverse* of the matrix whose columns are `v1` and `v2`.

Regarding the displacement vector `b`, it can be calculated as

```
b = Q1 - M * P1
```

The clarification here is that all of this is correct only if the fourth points are consistent with the transformation, i.e., if

```
M * P4 + b = Q4
```

otherwise the `Q`-quadrilateral is not an affine transformation of the `P`-quadrilateral.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the general barycentric coordinates of the point against the first quadrilateral, then applies the barycentric coordinates against the 2nd quadrilateral to find the "equivalent" point.

There are many different ways to compute the general barycentric coordinates for a point against a quadrilateral (or against a n-sided polygon). One of them is the Wachpress coordinates, which only works when the polygon is convex. For a convex polygon with vertices V0, V1,...Vn:

[image]

we can compute the Wachpress coordinates for point P within the polygon as

[image]

where A(a,b,c) is the signed area of triangle abc.

Then, we can compute the barycentric coordinates of P as

[image]

The equivalent point P* against the new polygon with vertices V*i (or quadrilateral in your case) can be computed as

P* = \summation(Wi * V*i) for i=0~n.